# Convert .pdf to .txt

Tags: r, pdf, tm

The problem [is not new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445659/use-r-to-convert-pdf-files-to-text-files-for-text-mining) on Stackoverflow, but I am pretty sure I am missing something obvious.

I am trying to convert a few .pdf files into .txt files, in order to mine their text. I based my approach on this [excellent script](https://gist.github.com/benmarwick/11333467). The text in the .pdf files is not composed by images, hence no OCR required.

```
# Load tm package
library(tm)

# The folder containing my PDFs
dest <- "./pdfs"

# Correctly installed xpdf from http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html

file.exists(Sys.which(c("pdfinfo", "pdftotext")))
[1] TRUE TRUE

# Delete white spaces from pdfs' names
sapply(myfiles, FUN = function(i){
  file.rename(from = i, to =  paste0(dirname(i), "/", gsub(" ", "", basename(i))))
})

# make a vector of PDF file names
myfiles <- list.files(path = dest, pattern = "pdf",  full.names = TRUE)

lapply(myfiles, function(i) system(paste('"C:/Program Files/xpdf/bin64/pdftotext.exe"', 
paste0('"', i, '"')), wait = FALSE))
```

It should create a .txt copy of any .pdf file in the `dest` folder. I checked for issues with the [path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701522/pdf-to-txt-in-r), for [white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701522/pdf-to-txt-in-r) in the path, for [xpdf common installation issues](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-November/180064.html) but nothing happens.

Here is the [repository](https://github.com/Maurizio-Mario/TextMining_WorldWar) I am working on. If it can be useful, I can paste the `SessionInfo`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the program work if you enter the commands on the command line?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I just tried, but nothing happened.

Comment: could use pdftools R package as an alternative?

Comment: @PeterEllis thank you for the suggestion, next time I will try it for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer:

But I recently discovered that with the current verions of tm (0.7-4) you can read pdfs directly into a corpus if you have pdftools installed (`install.packages("pdftools")`).

```
library(tm)

directory <- getwd() # change this to directory where pdf-files are located

# read the pdfs with readPDF, default engine used is pdftools see ?readPDF for more info
my_corpus <- VCorpus(DirSource(directory, pattern = ".pdf"), 
                               readerControl = list(reader = readPDF))
```